# Elementary Question in Calculation of Density of a Substance

Tags: geometry

If copper crystallises in FCC (Face-centred cubic) structure, then when we are told to calculate the density of copper, I can still do in two methods:

1) I can divide mass of a copper atom and its volume.
2) By using unit cells, mass of a unit cell divided by its volume.

What I don't understand is, why do we take the volume of the unit cell while dividing and not that of the spheres inside it? Because the spheres themselves do not occupy the same volume as that of the unit cell.

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Actually the mass is given only by the protons & neutrons, from their quarks arrangements, hence if you measure the proton from their estimated radius you will always find the same density for every substance on this universe, hence no, density is a macroscopic, and not a microscopic property of the matter....

Comment: Hence you must take the cell as the effecrive volume occupied, not the atoms itself.

Comment: I think what you tried to say is that it is the total volume the particles occupy themselves, excluding their own?

Comment: The total volume including everything

Comment: i get it thanks

Comment: The volume of the atoms should actually computed from the orbital schrodinger equation for each atom, and also assuming each links has a fixed statistical average distance -another orbital equation. Also assuming that the angles do not vary, or equivalently, there are no structural waves in the crystaline structure. I am completely sure you dont want any of these, and hence you are calculating the volume as $a^3$.